# Media Controller how to save to internal storage?

Tags: android

I am using Android `MediaController`. How can I save a recorded voice file to internal storage?

```
private String FILE;
FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/tempRecord.3gpp";
```

Comment: `to internal storage` AND `getExternalStorageDirectory()` do NOT match. The latter is called external storage as you can see looking at the function name.

Comment: ohh... sry, this part of code is write to store for external, but i want to know how to store in internal or cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage) it describes how to save to `internal` storage

In short use:

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
```

Where `context.getFilesDir()` returns a File representing an internal directory for your app.

To write to cache change `getFilesDir()` to `getCacheDir()`.

Comment: Thank you, but why the context is in redword, it say cant resolve symbol context what is it mean ?, sry, i am new to android studio

Comment: Just remove 'context.'.

Comment: Because you haven't share any of your code so I don't know in which `context` you call the file related code. It is usually the `Activity` class, if you call this code from inside your activity simply remove the `context` or provide `this`